# How can I return to the index.php from the blogs.php page

Tags: php, html, navigation

I try to go back to the index.php page from the blogs.php page. Here is my folder structure.

```
Folder structure
wbd:
|   index.php
|   template.php
|   tree.txt
|   
+---blogs
|       blogs.php
|       
+---inc
|       footer.php
|       header.php
|       loader.php
|       navbar.php
|       scripts.php
```

when I try to return back to the index page it shows there is no index page inside the blog page which is true. The Index page store in the main folder.

MY navbar.php look like this:

```html
<!-- nav menu -->

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="wbnav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="wbnav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a href="index.php" class=" nav-link">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="blogs/blogs.php" class="nav-link">Blog</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

I also try the header() function to go back to the index page but not working.

```
  <!-- nav menu -->

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="wbnav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="wbnav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a href="<?php header(" Location: ../index.php "); ?>" class=" nav-link">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="blogs/blogs.php" class="nav-link">Blog</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
```

How can I go back to the main index page?

Comment: the header is not used inside HTML. It is executed on the server

Answer (score 0):

Change `<a href="<?php header("Location: ../index.php"); ?>"`

into

`<a href="/"`

Comment: or `<a href="/index.php"`

Comment: yeah or that :/